# Downloading files based on if they already exist and if there is a folder for them Python

Tags: python, download, path, directory, file-exists

I am trying to create a script that downloads files from an FTP site based on whether I have a folder to put them in (based on date code) and whether or not I have already downloaded the file and have it in that folder. I believe I have the pieces to do this however, I am not sure how to combine them to get them to work.

So far to download the files from the FTP server I have the following code.

```
from ftplib import FTP
import os, sys, os.path
import re

def handleDownload(block):
    file.write(block)

ddir='U:/Test Folder'
os.chdir(ddir)
ftp = FTP('sidads.colorado.edu')
ftp.login()

print ('Logging in.')
directory = '/pub/DATASETS/NOAA/G02158/unmasked/2012/04_Apr/'

print ('Changing to ' + directory)
ftp.cwd(directory)
ftp.retrlines('LIST')

print ('Accessing files')

filenames = ftp.nlst() # get filenames within the directory
print (filenames)

for filename in filenames:
    if filename not in ['.', '..']:
        local_filename = os.path.join(ddir, filename)
        print(filename)

        with open(local_filename, 'wb') as f_output:
            ftp.retrbinary('RETR '+ filename, f_output.write)
ftp.quit()
```

To pull the string values I need from the filenames and to use these string values to determine whether or not the folder to put them in exists and whether or not the file exists I used the following code. (An important note is that the string values pulled from the filenames I download match the codes I used in my file paths therefore allowing me to match them)

```
for fname in filenames:
            tl = fname[16:20]
            t2 = fname[20:22]
            t3 = fname[22:24]
            if not tl: continue
            print (tl) # You can append the result to a list
            print (t2) # You can append the result to a list
            print (t3) # You can append the result to a list
if os.path.exists(os.path.join("U:/SWEModelConstruction/UnmaskedData/",t1,t2,t3)) == true and os.path.isfile("U:/SWEModelConstruction/UnmaskedData/",t1,t2,t3,filename) != true
```

Comment: If the folder structure is not there, do you need to create one or ignore that file?

Comment: ignore the file

Comment: basically, you join `dirr` to your filename to form local_filename and then in the second snippet, you use a different path. So which is the right path? Is the one in 1st snippet just a sample and the other the right one

Comment: The path in the first snippet is just a temporary location, my end goal is for the script to download the files into the file path in the second snippet, if and only if there is a folder already there for it and that I don't already have the file I'm downloading already downloaded in that folder. Sorry for the confusing question and thank you for the help.

Comment: Did the answer help?

Comment: Yes I think it will, So I just need to switch it so it does not create a file directory if there isn't one and for the file to download to the second snippet's directory instead of the first snippets. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

To follow your method,

```
def check_path(fname):
    tl = fname[16:20]
    t2 = fname[20:22]
    t3 = fname[22:24]
    if not tl: continue
    if os.path.exists(os.path.join(dirr,t1,t2,t3)) == true and os.path.isfile(dirr,t1,t2,t3,filename) != true


for filename in filenames:

    if filename not in ['.', '..']:
        check_path(filename)
        local_filename = os.path.join(ddir, filename)
        print(filename)

        with open(local_filename, 'wb') as f_output:
            ftp.retrbinary('RETR '+ filename, f_output.write)
```

You basically need to check the path is available, if not make directories.

And then, if the file is present using `os.path.isfile()` and that can be done in a simpler way, as (to make things more generalised)

```
def check_path(path):
    if not os.path.exists(path):
        return False
    return True

for filename in filenames:
    if filename not in ['.', '..']:
        local_filename = os.path.join(ddir, filename)
        path='/'.join(local_filename.split('/')[:-1])
        # check if dir exists otherwise create one
        # wrtie files that doesnt exists
        if os.path.exists(path) and not os.path.isfile(filename): 
            with open(local_filename, 'wb') as f_output:
                ftp.retrbinary('RETR '+ filename, f_output.write)
```

Hope it helps!